# "X" in stock solutions

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, lab-reagents

We prepare buffer solutions with concentration in terms of `x`, for example `50x` TAE buffer. How do we come up with `x`? Is `x` related to molarity in some sense? And how much can we concentrate the solution. We have `50x` TAE but usually `10x` TBE buffer, why is it so?

Comment: X simply stands for "times" like 50 times concentrated. And there are limits of how much of a certain substance can be dissolved in water. This limits stock concentrations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Chris. If X stands for "times" as you say, how much is 1 time, i.e, 1x, is it 1M, 0.05M as given here [link](http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/dilutions.html#stocks)? And is it same for all solutions?

Comment: That depends on your final concentration. If it is 100mM, then 10x is 1M (1000mM), 100x would be 10M.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1x is the final working concentration of the solution (it could be anything depending on the type of the solution). Stock solutions are made at a higher concentration; if it is 10 times more concentrated than the working solution then it is 10x.

> Why 50x TAE but 10x TBE?

The salts in TBE precipitate at higher concentrations. In other words, the salts in TBE have lower solubility compared to those of TAE. Therefore stock solutions of TBE are usually 10x or even 5x.

Comment: Thanks @WYSIWYG. Can you tell me how do we decide what should be 1x concentration by citing few examples?

Comment: @Biginer How to decide the 1x concentration: the first time when someone does that, then they 1. use rational guess 2. use trial and error, and settle on a concentration that is most optimal for the task. Subsequently, others follow it and tweak it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks @WYSIWYG. I came to the same conclusion when I discussed it with my peers. Thanks a lot!